# How to refer to a previous commit in git commit message

Tags: git, github

Is there a convention for referring to a previous commit in a git commit message?

Example commit message:

```
Fixed bug such and such introduced in a1b2c3e4
```

In particular, is there a convention that github.com will understand, and convert to a link?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Yup - GitHub will pick up references to SHAs and users/repos patterns using the [GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://docs.github.com/en/github/writing-on-github/autolinked-references-and-urls#commit-shas)

Specifically about linking to commits:

> A bit of the GitHub spice
>
> In addition to the changes in the previous section, certain references are auto-linked:
>
> - SHA: be6a8cc1c1ecfe9489fb51e4869af15a13fc2cd2
> - User@SHA ref: mojombo@be6a8cc1c1ecfe9489fb51e4869af15a13fc2cd2
> - User/Project@SHA: mojombo/god@be6a8cc1c1ecfe9489fb51e4869af15a13fc2cd2
> - #Num: #1
> - User/#Num: mojombo#1
> - User/Project#Num: mojombo/god#1

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful. I wonder if I'd get away with using an abbreviated SHA and still have it converted to a link..

Comment: Not sure - never tested it, but you could (if you're the only one using the remote, otherwise it gets a bit dangerous), push an abbreviated hash, then amend that commit if it doesn't work to the full one and push it again.

Comment: @Joel: [It works](https://github.com/mgarciaisaia/test-repo/commit/1528cb7af7323ae71abb8417f4befa6abc9c6569) ;-)

Comment: Thanks @desert69 for testing that

Comment: @Joel you still have to remember that it's an abbreviated SHA. If your repo gets big enough (kernel-like big, I know), your abbreviated SHA length could increase, leading you to ambiguities. So, you _can_ use an abbreviated SHA, but if it's not that much effort, I think it's allways better to use the full SHA. Github auto-trims it for you.

Comment: Is it just a GitHub feature or is it in any way supported by Git too? What if I am referring the SHA of a detached commit inside another commit's message? Will that make the SHA *reachable* or will it be pruned by garbage collector as *unreachable*?

Comment: I confirm, I put the full SHA and then github trimmed it for me. Quite useful.

Answer (score 16):

Guys at git answers the question [this way](https://git-scm.com/docs/SubmittingPatches#describe-changes):

> If you want to reference a previous commit in the history of a stable branch, use the format "abbreviated hash (subject, date)", like this:
>
> ```
> Commit f86a374 (pack-bitmap.c: fix a memleak, 2015-03-30)
> noticed that ...
> ```
>
> The "Copy commit summary" command of gitk can be used to obtain this format (with the subject enclosed in a pair of double-quotes), or this invocation of git show:
>
> ```
> git show -s --pretty=reference <commit>
> ```
>
> or, on an older version of Git without support for --pretty=reference:
>
> ```
> git show -s --date=short --pretty='format:%h (%s, %ad)' <commit>
> ```

###### Addition Feb 2024

I ended-up adding an alias `ref = show -s --pretty=reference`. It helps a lot.

Comment: Note that this is referring to a convention _for contributing to git itself_, rather than being a convention for git repositories in general.